# rsync doubles the size when copied from ext4 to NTFS-3G

Tags: rsync, ext4, ntfs-3g

I want to backup my `home` directory to an external SSD drive using `rsync`.

I'm on Arch Linux. My home is `ext4` (251G), the SSD is `NTFS-3G` mounted as `fuseblk` (512G).

The exact `rsync` invocation is:

```
rsync -aSh --info=progress2 --delete --exclude=/me/.cache /home/me /run/media/me/Samsung_T5/
```

Eventually, it fails with this being its last words:

```
        218.76G  99%   25.08MB/s    2:18:36 (xfr#2093188, ir-chk=1368/2286507)
rsync: write failed on "/run/media/me/Samsung_T5/me/a_file": No space left on device (28)
```

So, `rsync` allegedly copied around 218G of data and couldn't go furhter due to my SSD being full.

When I ask `du` how much data is there on my SSD `rsync` destination, it says 466G.

```
$ du -hs /run/media/me/Samsung_T5/me
466G    /run/media/me/Samsung_T5/me
```

This is weird. `rsync` tried to copy 281G, but it copied 218G and failed because it actually copied 466G.

What am I getting wrong here?

I do know that `NTFS` and `ext4` are different. But are they different enough to make my files more than 2x larger?
Am I copying more than I actually have in my `home`?

What would be the correct `rsync` procedure to back up my ~280G `home` to my SSD as something comparable in size with my `home`?

**UPDATE** [Thanks to the comments below]:

I have a large number of small files in my source directory and a certain amount of sparse files.
For example, there is a file 4K big in the source and 128K big in the destination. There is also a sparse file that is 12K in the source and 128K in the destination.

Also, I do have 244 hard links to different executables (e.g., shared libraries). Some of those hard links point to some relatively large files. For example, a version of `binutils` linker (`ld`) is around 7M and I have 4 hard links to it.

Comment: Do you have sparse files? I can see you're using `-S` to cope sparse file properly, but does the target filesystem support writing them? What does `du` say about any of the sparse files on the destination? Were they filled out?

Comment: In addition to sparse files, do you have a lot of very small files (say less than 100 bytes)? The minimum amount of space that a file uses can vary between filesystems.

Comment: @Kusalananda, They may be filled. For example, there is an `elf` for which `du` is 76K on the source and 512K on the destination. I don't know whether NTFS-3G is meant to support sparse files. Although, there are some people reporting some things online (e.g., https://superuser.com/a/1249438/180473). What would you do if you were me?

Comment: @icarus Seems like that's also the case. I have more than a million of those (e.g., auto-generated assembly files to test a single instruction are no more than 30 characters long).

Comment: Do you have many hard links? Note that `-a` does not preserve hardlinks, `-H` must be given additionally. AFAIK, NTFS-3G supports hardlinks.

Comment: @rexkogitans I do have 244 hard links. Mainly shared libraries and other executables. Thank you for `-H`, will check the documentation.

Comment: It may work better to backup the system into a **compressed `tar` archive file**. This way the ownership and permissions will be saved and can be restored when extracted into a linux file system. *And the small files and sparse files should not occupy too much space.* -- **If you still want to use `rsync`, you had better copy into a linux file system, e.g. 'ext4`**. This way it should work to copy hard links, small files and sparse files in a correct way and avoid that the backup size is bigger than the soulrce.

Comment: @sudodus The fact is that I do want to have an **incremental backup** of my `home`. Is there a technique to build tarballs incrementally (as `rsync` syncs only changed files)?

Comment: There are probably other tools, but you might look at `duplicity` and its gui [deja-dup](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup). It does incremental backups using tar files, optionally encrypted, optionally to a remote server.

Comment: @meuh Thank you, will give it a shot.

Comment: **Yes, there are tools for incremental backup using tar. It is easiest to use such tools**, but you can also look at the basics, for example at [this link](https://www.unixmen.com/performing-incremental-backups-using-tar/), where the crucial additonal option for incremental backup is `--listed-incremental=snapshot-file`

Comment: @sudodus Oh, didn't know that, thank you!

Comment: @meuh `duplicity` works for me. It does both archiving and compression (and encryption) so my ~280G `home` ends up in 136G backup. Can you please frame your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @sudodus your answer is also relevant. It may be useful to frame it as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: @foki check my answer: you need to restore hard links yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) and its gui [deja-dup](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup). It does incremental backups using tar files, optionally encrypted, optionally to a remote server.

It uses librsync and its rolling-checksum algorithm so that each incremental archive holds only the changed parts of files.

The home page says it handles Unix permissions, symbolic links, fifos, and
device files, but **does not preserve hard links**. If you have many large hard-linked
files it may be sub-optimal in the archive, but more importantly, you may also want to note separately which files are interlinked so that if you need to restore them you can put back the link.  If possible, converting to symbolic links would solve this problem.

---

You can look for hard links with something like

```
find /home/me -links +1 -type f -printf '%n %i %D %p\n' | sort -n
```

where the format string shows `%n` the number of links, `%i` the inode number, `%D` the *device* the file is on, and `%p` the pathname.  Lines with the same inode number and device are hard links. The device is only useful if you have mount points within the directory tree (as the same inode on a different device is not the same file).  Of course, hard links to files outside the tree cannot be handled, even by rsync.

Comment: I agree, that it is a good idea to convert hard links to symlinks in order to keep the size of the backup as small as possible when using a system that makes hard links into separate files.

Answer (score 1):

### Backup of a directory tree in an `ext4` file system

With an NTFS file system where you intend to write the backup, it may work better to backup the system into a compressed **`tar`** archive file. This way the ownership and permissions will be saved and can be restored when extracted into a linux file system. And the small files and sparse files should not occupy too much space.

If you still want to use `rsync`, you had better copy into a linux file system, e.g. `ext4`. This way it should work to copy hard links, small files and sparse files in a correct way and avoid that the backup size is bigger than the source.

> The fact is that I do want to have an **incremental** backup of my home. Is there
>   a technique to build tarballs incrementally (as rsync syncs only changed files)?

### Yes, there are tools for incremental backup using tar

It is easiest to use such a tool, as described in the answer by meuh, but you can also look at the basics, for example at [this link](https://www.unixmen.com/performing-incremental-backups-using-tar/), where the crucial additonal option for incremental backup is

```
--listed-incremental=snapshot-file
```